# Multiple Choice Field Saving

Tags: jquery, django, django-views

I am working on a RSVP app with a model as such:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    ...
    invite_list = models.ManyToManyField(GuestList, through='RSVP')


class RSVP(models.Model):
    guestlist = models.ForeignKey(GuestList)
    guest = models.ForeignKey(Guest, related_name='rsvp')
    ...
```

And I am attempting to create a multiple choice field form that allows users to select guests to add to `RSVP`. I am using jQuery to enhance the multiple select into 2 boxes, where selected items will appear in a box on the right.

In forms.py and using `crispy_forms`:

```
class RSVPSelectGuestForm(forms.Form):    
    guests = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = kwargs.pop('profile', None)
        guestlist_pk = kwargs.pop('guestlist_pk', None)
        super(RSVPSelectGuestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('guests', 
                id='guests-multiple-select',
            ),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Save'),
            ),       
        )
        self.fields['guests'].choices = [(obj.id, str(obj)) for obj in Guest.objects.filter(profile=profile)]
        self.fields['guests'].initial = [(obj.guest_id) for obj in RSVP.objects.filter(guestlist_id=guestlist_pk)]
```

I am able to render the select multiple element properly with the code above. I pass the kwargs from views to the form on `get_form_kwargs`.

Question now is a way to add/remove guests from the RSVP table in an efficient manner. I am hesitant to move on as I can't decide between my proposed solutions below:

1. *Process the form each time an event happens in the UI* - when user selects a guest, it is immediately added to the table; when user deselects a user, the guest is removed from the RSVP table. This could cause a lot of SQL read/writes if number of guests increases.
2. *Nothing is saved until the form is submitted* - From the post data, I would create a dictionary of selected options, compare it with the state when form was loaded, any new rows are added and missing rows are removed from the table. This only requires 2 SQL operations.

Could anyone help to suggest a good workaround or a better idea to solve this problem? Are there any issues I may have overlooked in my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with solution 2 for now as it was easier to achieve. Added the following methods to the form, when form is saved, 2 sets of data are created and compared. [It's easy the python way] Then we can just use 1 query each for bulk create or bulk delete. I have not tested this code on larger data sets yet.

```
def add_guests(self, added):
    RSVP.objects.bulk_create([
        RSVP(guestlist_id=self.guestlist_pk, guest_id=guest_pk) 
        for guest_pk in added
    ])

def remove_guests(self, removed):
    RSVP.objects.filter(guestlist_id=self.guestlist_pk, 
        guest_id__in=removed).delete()

def save(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data

    initial_data = set(self.initial_data)
    new_data = set([int(i) for i in data['guests']])

    added = new_data - initial_data
    removed = initial_data - new_data

    if added:
        self.add_guests(added)
    if removed:
        self.remove_guests(removed)
```

Any suggestions for improvements?